# access JSON array elements coming from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have

> {"user_id":"2790","freelancer_name":"","order_id":"8895","orderamount":"33638.00","payment_method":"","payment_desc":"","order_st":"newlink","total_comission":"3046.08","auto_increment_id":"2","po_box":"","country":"","order_add":"","shipping_co":"","weight":"0","fname":"","lastname":"","shippingcost":"0.00","paymentst":""}
>
> {"user_id":"2790","freelancer_name":"","order_id":"9121","orderamount":"0.00","payment_method":"","payment_desc":"","order_st":"newlink","total_comission":"0.00","auto_increment_id":"1","po_box":"","country":"","order_add":"","shipping_co":"","weight":"0","fname":"","lastname":"","shippingcost":"0.00","paymentst":""}

coming from this PHP code

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM order_list");
$myjsons = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myjsons[$i] = json_encode(array($row));
$myjsons[$i] = substr($myjsons[$i], 1, -1);

    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

I am trying to have access to each element but it seems that the array is just a string and doesn't have elements like user_id - order_id

here is the javascript to read the JSON

```
$("#txtfld").val(data[0]);
$("#resultTXT").val(data[1]);
```

I want have them like

txtfld = data[0].user_id and resultTXT = data[0].order_id ...

so the problem is to get the user id order id and etc

Comment: You don't have any arrays. Arrays have [ ... ]

Comment: `JSON.parse( str )` will parse the string and return the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using json_encode again (as in your `echo` statement) before returning the result to the user, for this line...

```
$myjsons[$i] = json_encode(array($row));
```

...don't json_encode inside the loop. You are double-encoding. It also appears you will not want to use `array()` here. So just do:

```
$myjsons[$i] = $row;
```

Actually, you can just do:

```
$myjsons[] = $row;
```

And get rid of:

```
$myjsons[$i] = substr($myjsons[$i], 1, -1);
```

Also, as someone pointed out in the comments, you'll want to use `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` on the client-side, though you'll probably want to conditionally add a library version of `JSON` where it is not supported (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) since it is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: well i am new with JSON, could you tell where can I find a good tutorial, I have tried learning from w3schools but the explanation is too simple and doesn't cover my issue

Comment: Have you tried http://www.json.org/js.html ? For your use case, basically in PHP, you will want to convert your final PHP array or object into JSON with a single call to the `json_encode` function (equivalent to `JSON.stringify` on the client side). That will represent the array/object as a string which can be sent over HTTP and whose contents can later be parsed (using `JSON.parse`, equivalent to `json_decode` in PHP) on the client side back into a usable array/object.